# jQuery chop slider but with HTML

Tags: jquery, slider

I started using Chop Slider, an amazing slideshow jquery plugin (http://www.idangero.us/cs/)
but the problem is, it didn't work for pure HTML.

What I am trying to do is make a simple effect for flipping between schedules I generate using php.

**If you want to see a live demo :**

1) Go to http://www.aisolutions.biz/horaire/demo.htm

2) You will see a schedule with a back and a next button. Try clicking those to see what happens (This is where I am trying to implement the Chop Slider effects)

**My alternatives are :**

1) Convert the tables generated into images (but I have no clue how, I looked at php.net and it seems that you can take a screenshot of a generated code on the server using php but only on Windows, I have linux :( )

2) Get a jQuery plugin that does some cool transitions as Chop Slider

Thanks in advance for any thoughts you are willing to share.

Comment: I couldn't get the demo to work, clicking Envoyer didn't do anything...

Comment: did you type in "INF1010 MTH1006" and wait for two blue rectangles to appear below the input field ?

Comment: Yeah, I type in that string, then a random bomb or star or something comes up, then nothing. Clicking envoyer does nothing. I get an error that points to this line: eval("response="+response); in your JS... This is in Chrome if it is useful.

Comment: oh thanks i fixed that! something weird was happening because i was disabling the button after it's being clicked :S but i will investigate in that later, so how about now ^^ ?

Comment: Now it's even worse - put in the text, hit return, page refreshes...

Comment: thats weird, it works perfectly for me.. any way, i setup a static page here : http://aisolutions.biz/horaire/demo.htm (works very well for me in chrome :) )

Comment: Can you setup a jsFiddle demo so we have something concrete to play with?  As it stands, I'm not sure if you're setting it up incorrectly or ChopSlider simply won't support your kind of content.

Comment: ok here we go http://jsfiddle.net/mc4KF/ (first time using this, so i hope i got it right)
i have used ChopSlider before, and got it working, but it doesn't seem to work with just HTML so i am wondering if someone has done this before with just HTML. should i setup the jsFiddle with Chop Slider ? because currently i am using the jquery cycle plugin as a replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Full disclosure: This is a plugin that I developed*

Check out [Basic jQuery Slider](http://basic-slider.com) - it's a really simple jQuery plugin for sliding any HTML content.

Comment: very nice m8, its getting hard to find such good plugins with 90% of the plugins being buggy or even not supported by major browser... keep up the good work ;) and gr8 website too :)